# Getting error while starting mysql by just typing in mysql terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, errors

I am getting an error while starting mysql, by just typing `mysql` in the  terminal:

The error is:

```
amtz@amtz-VPCEA23EN:~$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'amtz'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you start mysql from the command line.

When you type `mysql` in the command line it will launch the mysql-client not the mysql-server, which looks for the user/password options to be provided as arguments, if they aren't provided it will expect them to be specified in `~/.my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. If it still can't find the details there then it will then try the your current TTY user, which is what has happened to you.

If you want to login from the command line you can provide the username and password like so:

```
mysql -u <username> -p
```

If you don't want to have to do that every time then you can set the details in your `~/.my.cnf` file.

```
[client]
user=<username>
password="<password>"
```

If you do actually want to start the mysql-server then it would depend on your operating system. For instance on Ubuntu you would do that with:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Generally speaking you should be able to do

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: Out of the answers currently available, this is by far the clearest and most useful. I'd prefer to see links to documentation as well, and how to check if the service is running.

Answer (score -1):

Did someone `GRANT ... TO 'amtz'@'localhost';` ?  Apparently not.  When `mysql` (not `mqsql`) is first installed user=`root` can get in without a password.  That user should promptly assign a password to `root` and `GRANT` other users access.

Comment: This doesn't help the user who clearly doesn't understand how to connect to MySQL from the command line.  A more helpful answer would be "try typing 'mysql -uroot'", even though that wouldn't be particularly useful it would be better than this.

Answer (score -1):

It may the reason the user doesn't have permission to access mysql
Try with root user directly if mysql doesn't having any password orelse try "mysql -u username -p".